# How to set title text of button outside viewDidLoad

Tags: ios

How can I set the title text of a button without using inside `viewDidLoad`? I know how to set the title text of a button:

```
[button setTitle:@"Title" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

But I want to set the title text outside `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: have you set IBOutlet for your button ?

Comment: Improved grammar and removed irrelevant stuff. I assume `viewDidLoad` is a function or file (wasn't quite sure what "using inside..." meant...) Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Please create an `IBOutlet` of `UIButton` set title in the `xib/storyboard`

[image: Link UIButton in xib]

Comment: my button name's value comes from string variable